# How to pass in arguments in .desktop file

Tags: pop-os, .desktop, appimage

I'm trying to run an `.appimage` in Pop OS 22.04 that requires the command `--disable-gpu-sandbox`.

It works fine when launching from terminal, but when I create a `.desktop` file with the below:

```
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Path=/home/evan/installs
Exec=zoho64.AppImage --disable-gpu-sandbox
Name=ZohoMail
Icon=home/evan/installs/icon-zoho.png
```

I get the following error:

```
./zoho.desktop: line 6: --disable-gpu-sandbox: command not found
```

Sorry if this is a no-brainer, I'm a newbie just trying to leave Windows behind.

Comment: In what context are you getting this error? Are you trying to execute the .desktop file as  a shell script by any chance?

Comment: I put a first line `[Desktop Entry]` into my desktop files. - By the way, did you try according to [this tutorial](https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/run-appimages.html#integrating-appimages-into-the-desktop)? It seems to me, that you need not create any desktop file manually, there are appimage tools that should fix it.